# ERROR: Content Element with uid "61" and type "mask_container" has no rendering definition! (Typo3, Mask)

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I transfered a Typo3 website from the dev server to the live server. I can log into the backend, I cleared all caches, activated all necessary extensions. In backend everything seems to run fine.

However, in frontend everything is rendered correctly except the Mask-elements. In place of the mask-elements I get this output:

"ERROR: Content Element with uid "61" and type "mask_container" has no rendering definition!"

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you forgot to include the "Fluid Styled Content" and the "Mask" templates in your site template under "include static from extension".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it. Static templates were included. I had copied all folders in /fileadmin and /typo3conf. I also had copied the database, imported an export of the dev server database.

But still the paths in the Mask configuration were wrong. I had to correct the paths manually. That fixed it.